# Cannot start nuxt: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined - Nuxt3

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, nuxt-auth

Getting Error while Migrating Nuxt 2 to Nuxt 3 with nuxt-auth but showing error in axios/lib.

```
` ERROR  Cannot start nuxt:  Cannot read property 'options' of undefined                                    12:46:12 PM

  at axiosModule (node_modules/@nuxtjs/axios/lib/module.js:12:13)
  at installModule (node_modules/@nuxt/kit/dist/index.mjs:450:101)
  at async initNuxt (node_modules/nuxt/dist/index.mjs:2619:7)
  at async load (node_modules/nuxi/dist/chunks/dev.mjs:183:9)
  at async Object.invoke (node_modules/nuxi/dist/chunks/dev.mjs:233:5)
  at async _main (node_modules/nuxi/dist/cli.mjs:48:20)`
```

this is my `nuxt.config.ts`

```
// https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/auth-next'
  ]
})
```

This is my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "nuxt-app",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "dev": "nuxt dev",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "preview": "nuxt preview",
    "postinstall": "nuxt prepare"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^18",
    "nuxt": "^3.4.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/auth-next": "5.0.0-1667386184.dfbbb54",
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.13.6"
  }
}
```

Nuxt3 docs mention to use Sidebase/auth-next cause of inprocess of auth-next
but still couldn't get over this error!